# MongoDB - finding most matching document based on its properties

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to find a document which have most similar documents based on multiple fields.

Example:

Collection with documents:

```
{ _id: 1, dept: "tech", description: "lime green computer",contact:"John",no:"2763926932" }
{ _id: 2, dept: "tech", description: "wireless red mouse",contact:"Adam",no:"2434358465" }
{ _id: 3, dept: "kitchen", description: "green placemat",contact:"Bruce",no:"2763934932" }
{ _id: 4, dept: "kitchen", description: "red peeler",contact:"Tom",no:"27639343932" }
{ _id: 5, dept: "food", description: "green apple",contact:"Clark",no:"2763934532" }
{ _id: 6, dept: "food", description: "red potato",contact:"Tony",no:"2963926932" }
```

Here each field have a weighted:

dept : 10
description: 7
contact: 4

So if I search a document with dept = tech , description = lime green computer and contact= Tony

It should return document with _id =1 , ie

```
{ _id: 1, dept: "tech", description: "lime green computer",contact:"John",no:"2763926932" }
```

It tried creating index and add weights to each field as specified [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/#control-search-results-with-weights).

```
db.blog.createIndex(
   {
     dept: "text",
     description: "text",
     contact: "text",
     no:"text"
   },
   {
     weights: {
       dept: 10,
       description: 7,
         contact:4
     },
     name: "TextIndex"
   }
 )
```

But when I tried to query the database , its not able to match any documents.

Could you please provide a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text) operator to perform a text search on the content of the fields indexed with a text index.

```
db.blog.find({$text:{$search:"tech lime green computer Jhon"}}, { score: { $meta: "textScore" } });

{  "_id" : 2,  "dept" : "tech",  "description" : "wireless red mouse",  "contact" :     "Adam",  "no" : "2434358465",  "score" : 11 }
{  "_id" : 1,  "dept" : "tech",  "description" : "lime green computer",  "contact" : "John",  "no" : "2763926932",  "score" : 25 }
{  "_id" : 3,  "dept" : "kitchen",  "description" : "green placemat",  "contact" : "Bruce",  "no" : "2763934932",  "score" : 5.25 }
{  "_id" : 5,  "dept" : "food",  "description" : "green apple",  "contact" : "Clark",  "no" : "2763934532",  "score" : 5.25 }
```

MongoDB returns all documents where any of searching words matched.
The `{ score: { $meta: "textScore" } }` expression provides information on the processing of the `$text` operation.

To perform searching only for specific documents, you may add `field:value` into your query.

```
db.blog.find(
    { dept: "tech", $text:{$search:"tech lime green computer Jhon" } }, 
    { score: { $meta: "textScore" } })
.sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )

{  "_id" : 1,  "dept" : "tech",  "description" : "lime green computer",  "contact" : "John",  "no" : "2763926932",  "score" : 25 }
{  "_id" : 2,  "dept" : "tech",  "description" : "wireless red mouse",  "contact" : "Adam",  "no" : "2434358465",  "score" : 11 }
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/